# How to set icon onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, icons, contextmenu

I try like this but is does't show

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Menu");

    menu.add(0, EDIT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_edit).setIcon(R.drawable.edit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Context menus do not show icons, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare But there should be an alternative to it though. That's how we see it when long touching on favorites items in the Phone app, for example, It even has a divider. What do you think they use instead? PopupWindow? But why don't they offer icons in the items, if that's what they use?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "What do you think they use instead?" -- if you are referring to Google's Phone app as seen on a Pixel 3, they probably used a `CardView` wrapped around something. It is possible that's in a separate system window (e.g., `PopupWindow`), but it would not have to be.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. Thank you!